# Use AVD Manager UICC (SIM) Certificate to sign APK

Tags: android, certificate, sim-card, lte

My goal is to test VoLTE (voice-over-LTE) settings on Android 6.0, and to do so I have to use CarrierConfig & TelephonyManager APIs.

These APIs requires **Carrier authentication-level**, it means : signing app with one of the certificate authorized into the ACL (Access Control List) of the **UICC** (a.k.a SIM card for casuals, but in reality, SIMs are stored into the UICC).

I have read that the **AVD Manager possess it's own simulated UICC**, and I can see some SIM info into the virtual device. I need to be able to :

- Either add a key into the ACL of the UICC (which is apparently doable OTA (over-the-air) from this post : [Sign App with UICC Carrier Privileges Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551420/sign-app-with-uicc-carrier-privileges-certificates) )
- Either get an existing key and certificate which is authorized in the UICC, and sign my app with it.

The second option seems easier, but in both case I can not find good information.

Thank you very much for your enlightenment on this subject !

**EDIT** :

I also found this subject : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111928/how-to-change-original-unchangeable-iccid-sim-card-serial-from-an-avd but it basically lead to a blog I've checked before (to change SIM Serial Number, IMEI and IMSI) and the AVDManager source code is not available anymore.

Comment: Did you solve your problem and if so could you share solution? I also need to use getIccAuthentication() method of TelephonyManager and app needs UICC Carrier privileges. How to get these from AVD?

Comment: @Alex I am working on similar case, Let us know if you were able to find any solutions

Comment: unfortunatly, I didn't solved the issue and it's been a while since I've worked on it. I'm not 100% sure to remember, but I think I couldn't test the settings with a custom app, but only checks for the settings support configuration directly in source code of the phone ROMs.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the reply man, I really appreciate that.